# Ckeditor - why does my code fire twice? And how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I downloaded the onchange plug-in (https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/onchange). Connect it in config.js:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'onchange';
```

I wrote the following code in config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    var editor = ev.editor;
    editor.on('change', function() {
        console.log('zzz');
    });
});
```

And now when I write something in my editor, zzz is output twice. Why is that? Should be output once.

Comment: What are you writing in the editor? If you're writing a couple characters, I'd expect that to be considered a couple changes. Have you looked what constitutes a "change"?

Comment: Even if I type one character - everything also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the line:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'onchange';
```

And everything began to work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    var editor = ev.editor;
    console.log('aaa');

    editor.on('change', function() {
        console.log('zzz');
    });
});
```

Is 'aaa' output twice also? I'm guessing that you're instantiating the editor more than once.

Comment: No. "aaa" was printed only once.